# Can you convert the Christoffel Symbol to the form of a scalar?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

Given some tensor $T_{\mu v}$, you can use the metric tensor to contract its indices, converting it into the form of a scalar:
$$g^{\mu v}T_{\mu v}=T$$
Even though the Christoffel Symbol is not a tensor, can you convert it to the form of a scalar in a similar fashion?
$$\Gamma_{abc} \rightarrow \Gamma$$
Maybe by contracting it with itself?
$$\Gamma_{abc} \Gamma^{abc} = \Gamma$$
If such a form of the Christoffel symbol is allowed, can you take the contravariant derivative of its scalar form?

I apologize if this question is a bit dull, I am fairly new to the subject. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this being "allowed" - if you know how the Christoffel symbol transforms, you should be able to just compute on your own whether $\Gamma_{abc}\Gamma^{abc}$ transforms like a scalar or not, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "convert the Christoffel symbol to the form of a scalar". If you simply mean as you suggested in your post, $\Gamma_{abc}\Gamma^{abc}$, then no that won't work (just consider a 1-dimensional manifold: in the obvious cartesian coordinate system, this is $0$, but if you change to some non-trivial coordinate system $\Gamma$ won't be $0$, and since there's only one component, this is very easily seen).

Recall that the transformation law for $\Gamma^a_{\,bc}$ between two coordinate charts is of the form
\begin{align}
\Gamma(y)&=\Gamma(x)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial y\partial y},
\end{align}
dressed up with appropriate indices. It is this second term which causes all the 'issues'. So, very roughly speaking, to create something tensorial, you have to consider differences in $\Gamma$'s. For instance, the Riemann curvature tensor field $R^a_{\,bcd}$ is made of $\Gamma$, its partial derivatives, and their differences:
\begin{align}
R&\sim\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial x}+\Gamma\Gamma-\Gamma\Gamma,
\end{align}
again with appropriate indices which I don't feel like filling in now.
You can definitely construct scalar functions out of the Riemann curvature by contraction, e.g the Ricci scalar curvature $R=g^{bd}R^a_{\,bad}$, or certain quadratic expressions like $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$ or $R_{ab}R^{ab}$, where $R_{ab}:=R^{s}_{\,asb}$ is the Ricci curvature tensor. You can consider their derivatives etc.